# How to access secrets in node.js with Hashicorp Vault

Tags: mysql, node.js, hashicorp-vault

I have just set up Vault from Hashicorp on my Ubuntu 18.04 backend server. It runs a node.js backend server which used to use environment variables to store data for the MySQL database. However, I figured this was unsecure, hence why I changed to Vault. I have now stored all secrets inside the Vault and I can access it in my node.js application like this:

```
const rootKey = "hidden"
const unsealKey = "alsohidden"

var options = {
    apiVersion: 'v1',
    endpoint: 'https://url.com:8200',
    token: rootKey
};

var vault = require("node-vault")(options);
vault.unseal({ key: unsealKey })
    .then(() => {
        vault.read('secret/db_host')
          .then((res) => console.log("result:",res.data.value))
          .catch((err) => console.error("error:",err));
    });
```

This results in the correct host address printed in my console logs. However, this leaves me with two questions:

**1. How can I use the retrieved information in my MySQL connection? I currently do this with the environment variables:**

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST, // how can I call the vault variables here?
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_BASE,
    ssl      : {
          ca   : fs.readFileSync('hidden'),
          key  : fs.readFileSync('hidden'),
          cert : fs.readFileSync('hidden'),
    },
    dateStrings: true
});
```

**2. If I store the rootKey and unsealKey as constants in my node.js application, what's the point of secrecy? I figure there should be a way to handle this properly, because there is not much different now as to just store the credentials in my .js file straight away..**

Comment: How did you set up Vault from Hashicorp on my Ubuntu machine or let me know steps for setting up in Macbook.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use your root key to access secrets. Vault provides several [authentication methods](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/token.html). For example - user-pass pairs, github authentication (using token), LDAP, k8s and more...

Using one of the authentication method you will get a vault token with a [policy](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies.html). This policy will allow you the access only your relevant secrets.

Another great place to read about Vault: [Learn Vault](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/)

If you are using kubernetes you can read [this guide](https://medium.com/ww-engineering/working-with-vault-secrets-on-kubernetes-fde381137d88) and this [one](https://medium.com/@gmaliar/dynamic-secrets-on-kubernetes-pods-using-vault-35d9094d169)

edit: regarding the first question, it depends on how you decide to load the secrets - you can load them from file, from process.env or directly set them using node-vault package. I personally write them to file from a different [process](https://github.com/WealthWizardsEngineering/kube-vault-auth-init) and load them to process.env with [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.